# Ping a minecraft server with javascript (no plugins)?

Tags: php, javascript, sockets, ping, minecraft

I'm creating this website which lists minecraft servers. Basically I'm trying to ping all these servers as they are displayed. Solving this problem with php doesn't quite solve it for me, pinging all the servers takes time, and I know javascript can execute multiple "pings" at the same time. How would I do this?

The PHP code I'm using now:

```
class minecraft_server
{
    private $address;
    private $port;

    public function __construct($address, $port = 25565){
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->port = $port;
    }

    public function get_ping_info(&$info){

        $starttime = microtime(true);
        $socket = @fsockopen($this->address, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, 1.0);
        $stoptime  = microtime(true);
        $ping = round(($stoptime-$starttime)*1000);

        if ($socket === false){
            return false;
        }

        fwrite($socket, "\xfe\x01");

        $data = fread($socket, 256);

        if (substr($data, 0, 1) != "\xff"){
            return false;
        }

        if (substr($data, 3, 5) == "\x00\xa7\x00\x31\x00"){
            $data = explode("\x00", mb_convert_encoding(substr($data, 15), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2'));
        }else{
            $data = explode('§', mb_convert_encoding(substr($data, 3), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2'));
        }

        if (count($data) == 3){
            $info = array(
                'version'       => '1.3.2',
                'motd'          => $data[0],
                'players'       => intval($data[1]),
                'max_players'   => intval($data[2]),
                'ping'          => $ping
            );
        }else{
            $info = array(
                'version'       => $data[0],
                'motd'          => $data[1],
                'players'       => intval($data[2]),
                'max_players'   => intval($data[3]),
                'ping'          => $ping
            );
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And you call the function with:

```
$server = new minecraft_server(IP, PORT);
if (!$server->get_ping_info($info)){
    echo "Offline";
}else{
    print_r($info);
}
```

How would I create a similar thing in javascript?

Comment: JavaScript can not call external domains unless they have CORS enabled. Create a webservice where an Ajax call to your server can get the status.

Comment: @epascarello: That's not entirely true, there are workarounds like JSONP. But barring the Minecraft server exposing an HTTP interface, the odds of doing this from JavaScript (CORS or JSONP) are low...

Comment: I agree with @epascarello, AJAX is the way to go here. A server on a reasonable connection can do a set of pings extremely quickly.

Comment: +1 for @epascarello. Say you have 100 people hit your site in 10 seconds, then their browsers will each send a ping to all of the servers, and the server operators will despise you. It is better to have your server send *one* ping every X seconds, cache the result, and report the response back to the client.

Comment: I think the OP needs to learn about services.

Answer (score 1):

In your place, I probably would have set up a script that, when called, pings the selected server and prints a parse-able result, then call that script using Ajax whenever a ping needs to be sent.